# How to create new thread every interation of for-loop?

Tags: python

How can I create a new instance every iteration so I won't have to wait till the previous iteration has finished?
I have this for loop atm:

```
for f in Lines:
 with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    try:
        target=ydl.download([f])
    except:
        print("---------")
```

I want to call a function `ydl.download([f])` every line but I don't want to wait for the function to complete.

I tried using `Thread(target=ydl.download([f])).start()` but it still waits for the function to complete.

Comment: Launch them in separate processes, or use asyncio.

Comment: You're doing the download and then passing the result of the download as the thing to be executed by the Thread object.  I wonder how that even runs without giving some kind of error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `Thread(target=ydl.download, args=([f],)).start()`?

Because what you said you tried is equivalent to:

```
value = ydl.download([f])
Thread(target=value).start()
```

Comment: I was missing the `args=([f]`. Ty, this solved the problem.